# calling one app from another, Android sdk?

Tags: android

My question is, is it possible to call one app from another?
           It would be very helpful if anyone had an answer or solution.

-Chris-

Comment: Or like linking two apps to eachother?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call one android application from another android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

For example:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.theotherapp", "com.example.theotherapp.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

This is called an **explicit intent**, because you're explicitly stating which component should respond to it. You can also use **implicit intents**, in which you specify what kind of component you expect and the OS and/or the user selects the most appropriate one.

If you can choose, implicit intents are preferred.

Comment: Thanks, do i have to set special permissions or instrumentations inside the manifest?

Comment: Or, is it possible to put the hole app inside the other app?

Comment: You don't need special permissions to use intents. You can have more than one component in one app, but whole apps cannot be contained inside other apps.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking on the check box outline to its left.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html, more specifically at the "Application Components" section.

There are many ways to make two applications talk to each other - and they're explained there.

Comment: Thats the first place I looked. It wasn't much help. Hard to understand. thanks for the help though.