# Starting One Android App from Another App

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

What is the best way to start one android app from another app?  Is it to send custom broadcast event and have broadcast receiver of other app catch this event and do a start activity on something?  Thanks

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application is the oldest and the best QA on the theme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an Intent:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Use Context.startActivity() to just launch, or Activity.startActivityForResult() if you want to get a result when it's done.

If you are tightly coupled with the other application, you can use an explicit Intent.  Otherwise, send an implicit Intent.

Comment: Hey sparky are you in Munich.  I used to do work for one of automotives there.  Do you have URL on profile?

Answer (score 3):

best way is call by intent like this

http://www.lacherstorfer.at/haris_blog/2008/03/android-howto-invoke-a-phone-c.html

Comment: what if app is down?  How is this better than using broadcast receiver? Thanks

Comment: If app is down, it will be raised by the intent.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try
{
    String packageName = "com.example.package";
    Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
}
```