# How to launch an application from another application in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting One Android App from Another App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281910/starting-one-android-app-from-another-app)

We are developing an android application let say `com.example.helloone` and another android application `com.test.hellocalled`.Here both are two different packages,i want to call `com.test.hellocalled` application from `com.example.helloone`.Can you suggest regarding same?

Comment: Asked many times. Please use the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=starting+another+app+from+my+app+in+Android) feature before posting new questions.

Comment: That one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application is older and better

Answer (score 4):

In your activity, you can use

```
if(isAppInstalled("com.other.package"))
{
    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    nextIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.other.package","com.other.package.Activity"));
    startActivity(nextIntent);
}
```

Comment: Sorry what exactly i mean that whether one application launch other application of android . Tried the above case but did not work out..

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate; if your actual question is different, please ask again, but make sure to explain clearly what is different about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to tag something as a repeat, but a quick google search brings up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application) which is the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Either u can start an activity with an Intent that is similar to the one of the application that you wish to launch or u can launch the application using its file path as shown below:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
 intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/the full path to your file"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");          "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

context.startActivity(intent);