# How to send user to another application

Tags: android

I'm trying to send the user of my OCR project to the OFFLINE Google Translator but I don't know what should I use to achieve that...

I'v searched alot but nothing meet what i want.

i thought about using Intent with the action " View "

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
```

i see this 
[it's not what actually i need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408062/how-to-launch-an-application-from-another-application-in-android)

help plz

Comment: than whats the problem ? and is any app OFFLINE Google Translator??

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch an intent referencing the app id (package name) of the app in question. Try this:

```
public static void launchGoogleTranslateApp(Activity activity) {
    PackageManager manager = activity.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```