# How to call one application's activity from another in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I have two standalone applications i.e A and B. A needs some functionality from B. Application A calls an intent of Application B. Application B receives the request and process it and send back the result to A. Just like the Zxing Barcode Application.

How could i achieve the above? Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call one android application from another android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.your.package","package.class");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.package");
startActivityForResult(intent );
```

Replace `com.your.package` with `Application B` package id.

Comment: I have two different projects. Infact I want to integrate my new application B into Application A. I use your code, but it stop the application.
P.S: I am beginner in android development.

Comment: Try running the second option and replace `com.your.package` with the application B package.

Comment: I have used some library in application B. and now by integrating with Application A, it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: I can now call an activity in B from A but I don't get the result back in my calling activity. I used startActivityforResult() and I get back to the calling activity after finishing from B but couldn't get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it reminds me of startActivityForResult method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Rather good example:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/